# Recommended architecture for bulk-refreshing Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce

We would like to keep Salesforce synced with data from our organization's back-end. The organizational data gets updated by nightly batch processes, so "real-time" syncing to Salesforce isn't in view. We intend to refresh Salesforce nightly, after our batch processes complete.

We will have somewhere around 1 million records in Salesforce (some are Accounts, some are Contacts, and some belong to custom objects).

We want the refresh to be efficient, so it would be nice to send only updated records to Salesforce. One thought is to use Salesforce's Bulk API to first get all records, then compare to our data, and only send updated records to Salesforce.  But this might be an expensive GET.

Another thought is to just send all 1 million records through the Bulk API as upserts to Salesforce - as a "full refresh".

What we'd like to avoid is the burden/complexity of keeping track of what's in Salesforce ourselves (i.e. tables that attempt to reflect what's in Salesforce, so that we can determine the changes to send to Salesforce).

Comment: Hi @Dave, there is a new stackexchange site specific to Salesforce at salesforce.stackexchange.com. Come join the community over there! :)

Comment: Thanks Ralph! I'll take your advice and re-post this over there; as I see this question only got 8 views. :) Appreciated.